# getting events from facebook page

Tags: ios, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

So I need to get the events for a facebook page (in JSON format if possible). I'm using iOS and I know how to implement the data after I get it but I just don't know how to get the actual data from facebook. 
I've tried the graph api but it requires an access token to do what I want. I saw an app that didn't require the user to go in and allow a facebook app access to get the events from a page and I want the same thing.

https://graph.facebook.com/HardasNailsministry/  <= this works
https://graph.facebook.com/HardasNailsministry/events <= this does not work (requires access token)

So... is there a way to get that list of events without the access token? 
Or is there a way to get that access token without requiring the user to allow an app access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

You don't need to make the user allow access to his/her account in order to get the access token.

What I did was I went to my facebook developer page and created an app. It gave me an app ID and app secret. I used that in the following url to get the access_token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Then I took the result and added it to my graph API request string.

Comment: Sorry about the question, but how we can get events list ?

Comment: Hello matt, i´m struggling with this a lot!! i use your answer(by the way thanks) and i got the access token, but now i´m having trouble in how to do the rest of the process...could you post the code below in how did you use this? is it here:"FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:" because i want to get the events of a facebook page that i have created. could you please help me?!.