# RSS format for events from facebook page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

I was successfully able to get the RSS feed of a page in FB using this URL.

```
https://facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID_HERE&format=rss20
```

It returns values in RSS format. Then using regular `NSXMLParser` methods or some so parsing protocols, I was able to parse them.But unfortunately it returns all the details of the page, such as Events, notes and etc.

I would like to get the events only. It is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124159/getting-events-from-facebook-page), we can achieve it using Graph API once we obtain the general access token. My question is, can't we simply get the RSS feed for events in facebook page like the URL above? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the FB API and all RESTful methods of accessing data from Facebook are being retired in favour of the Graph API and FQL, whichever you prefer.

The Graph API way is to parse the JSON returned by:
`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events?access_token=TOKEN_HERE`

After skim-reading the FQL docs, I can't find a way to do it using that. So, it looks like your best hope lies with the Graph API.

Comment: Thank you for the response Callum :-) I found a work around to do it! Hope that works or I should go with Graph API :-)

Comment: RSS feed itself is grouped with different tags.. So that event can be read seperately.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would really like to know how to do this. We have a facebook page and have a livestream from this page on our website. Now we would like to have a list of events from the facebook page in the website as well. Is it posible at all?